# Can't find the night time Mega stones?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

It's been awhile since I've played Pokemon X but just to make sure, I battled my rival again in Kiloude city and then went to Anistar city to see if the professor was at the sundial -- which he was not. I guess I must have upgraded my Mega Ring before I took a break, but I can't find any of the stones. at around 8:20 I went searching for the Mawileite on the second floor of the Shabboneau castle but it was not there. I'm thinking of deleting my data and starting over because this is really bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade your mega ring before being able to find them at night. You need to visit the sundial in Anistar between 8:00 pm and 9:00 pm, that's when the dial will be active (and you'll find the professor there) and the same time you'll be able to find other mega stones.